# What are the sealing adhesives for high vacuum system?

Tags: experimental-physics, vacuum, experimental-technique, experimental-technology, adhesion

Recently, I have a project that needs to use a high vacuum system. During the construction process, I encountered a problem: I need to stick mica or glass to the window of the copper wall (one side is the atmosphere and the other side is a vacuum lower than 1 Pascal), which requires adhesive. However, after browsing the information, I found that the cured adhesive is easy to release gas and destroy the vacuum in the system. So now I need to find a glue that will not release gas after curing. I heard that hysol 1C may meet the requirements, but I got a negative answer after asking the local seller, so I published this for help.
[image: Glue is shown in red, copper in black and glass in blue.]

*Glue is represented in red, copper is represented in black and glass is represented in blue.*

Comment: What does NASA use? I realize outgassing in space isn't the same as outgassing and ruining a closed vacuum but it does not sound like you looked. Can you braze the glass into place? Also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glass-to-metal_seal

Comment: please clarify: which material do you want to glue to which material, and where is air and where is vacuum?

Comment: Thank you for your reminder. I added this picture to the question. Glue is represented in red, copper is represented in black and glass is represented in blue.

Comment: In practical applications, not only glass, but also mica and other non-metals are needed. Since these non-metals have a high melting point and are not sure if they wet with copper, I thought glue would be a better option.

Comment: Hm. Most people worried about “outgassing” are thinking of a volatile material like water ice, which will sublimate until all of the ice has escaped into your vacuum pump. But you are asking about using an adhesive as part of the barrier between air and vacuum? That is not the usual design for a vacuum window.

Comment: Yes, glue is used to close the gap between non-metallic materials and metal materials. Therefore, a certain area of cured glue will be exposed to vacuum atmosphere.

Comment: There are products like “Torr Seal” on the market. This one claims to be good down to a nano-torr.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason you would want or need to expose the glue to the barrier between atmosphere and vacuum. Use an o-ring with some vacuum grease for that interface, and affix the window to the copper outside of that interface using whatever method you like.

This could be something as simple as some straps to hold it in place or something as complicated as a custom-made flange.

Comment: This will make manufacturing a little more complicated, but I think it is also a way to consider.